# Full Calendar in Asp.net Webforms - Submit updated events

Tags: asp.net, webforms, fullcalendar

I am using Asp.net Webforms and FullCalendar library. The client side works as expected. I have added a submit button to the calendar. On submit, i want to get all the changed or added events from the calendar and post them to database. Clientevents gets all events of the calendar, however i want to get only the changes between the calendar and datasource. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [How to send only updated events as json to server on fullcalendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33840037/how-to-send-only-updated-events-as-json-to-server-on-fullcalendar)

You can include your own field on event object (like isNew / isUpdated) and filter the events by that field when you collect all events.

```
eventData = {
                title: title,
                start: start,
                end: end,
                isNew: true, //your own field
                isUpdated: true, //your own field
            };

 var eventsFromCalendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function (event) {
                    return event.isNew == true;
                });
```